# If find 4 digit number print the number and next row value in csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have data in csv format:

```
125867569,98652343,7012,879456217,20121221,7065,758964231,856421345
```

My desired output:

```
7012,879456217,7065,758964231
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you need in words. Presumably, you don't want a command that simply prints `7012,879456217,7065,758964231`, so please explain how you get from your input to your desired output. Also, please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<NF-1;i++) if (length($i)==4 && int($i)==$i) printf("%s,%s,", $i,$(i+1))}' input_file
```

If you want the "absolute overkill" version which removes unnecessary `,` and adds newlines to the output, try

```
awk -F, '{if (g) printf("\n"); f=0; for (i=1;i<NF-1;i++) if (length($i)==4 && int($i)==$i) {if (f) printf(","); else f=1; printf("%s,%s", $i,$(i+1)); g=1}} END{if (g) printf("\n")}' input_file
```

Comment: You could modify it to do that, though, by replacing `if (length($i)==4)` with `if ($i ~ /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)` (portable, with collation locale set to `C`) or `if ($i ~ /[[:digit:]]{4}/)` (GNU awk only). BTW, I think you mistyped the FS, it should be `,`, not `;`.

Comment: Thanks but Syntax error:  near %s

Comment: yes I have changed the FS but this is throwing syntax error

Comment: @Amit10504 There seems to be one stray `"` in the `awk` command and one `"` missing. Try removing the `"` after the `4` and modify the `printf` command to `printf("%s,%s",$i,$(i+1))`.

Comment: yes it is working but it joined the 4 digit with immediate next value 7012,8794562177065,758964231    here 7065 joined with the immediate number  comma is missing between them

Comment: @Amit10504, I add the comma. But this comma will appear also on the end of the line :)

Comment: Got it thanks printf("%s,%s"",",$i,$(i+1)).... It worked as expected with this. Thankyou so much for your help... Really appricate your help@AdminBee

Answer (score 0):

If your file never contains quoted commas or newlines, you can just use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f3,4,6,7 file.csv
```

- `-d` specifies the delimiter
- `-f` specifies the columns to output

Comment: Based on the title and some creative guessing, I think the OP only want to print fields whose length is exactly 4 and the field immediately after those.

Comment: Yes terdon you are right.. 4 digit number is random it can come in any place and I need the number and the field immediately after those

Comment: @Amit10504 then please [edit] your question and clarify as I requested almost an hour ago! Otherwise, people will waste their time, and yours, giving answers that don't help you.

Comment: Also, what should happen if the last number has length 4? What if the numbers of length 4 are consecutive, e.g. `1234,1234,123456`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) do |row|
    puts row.each_cons(2)
            .select {|pair| pair.first =~ /^\d{4}$/}
            .flatten
            .to_csv
  end
' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it multiple ways:

Method-1: GNU sed(extended regex enabled)

Explained: Initially place a marker at the beginning of pattern space. Look two fields to the right and if we see a 4-digit number to our immediate right, make the marker jump two fields to the right. OTW, make the marker jump one field AND erase the field from the pattern space. This process stops when the marker reaches the end of pattern space.At that point whatever's left in the pattern space is the answer.

```
$ sed -re '
     s/^/\n/
     :a;/\n$/!{
       s/\n([0-9]{4},[^,]+(,|$))/\1\n/;ta
       s/\n[^,]+(,|$)/\n/;ta
      }
      s/,?\n$//;/./!d
 ' file.csv

$ perl -F, -lane '$,=",";
    print  /(?:^|,)(\d{4},[^,]+)/g;
' file.csv 

$ perl -F, -lane '$,=",";
    shift(@F) =~ /^(\d{4})$/
      and push(@A, $1, shift(@F))
        while @F > 1;
    print splice @A if @A;
' file.csv

$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{
    N = split($0, a, FS)
    $0 = ""
    for ( i=j=1; i<N; )
      if ( a[i] ~ /^[0-9]{4}$/ )
        for ( k=0; k<2; k++ )
          $(j++) = a[i++]
      else
        ++i
  }NF' file.csv
```